# How to avoid Node.Js app taking all the resources?

Tags: node.js, performance, express

At the moment there's an iterative algorithm in my Node.Js express app that is so heavy on the server that it uses up all its resources.

I was wondering if there were any ways to limit the resources used by each process, so, for example, the memory or the processor usage never goes about 70% to leave the resources for other software running on the server.

I'm running it on a Linux Ubuntu box, on top of Nginx server, using PM2 to run the Node.Js app.

I know it's a pretty general question but that is why I'm asking it also to better understand the specific direction to move in with this problem...

Thank you!

Comment: The answer isn't specific to Node.js... it's dependent on your OS.  Also, if you're only utilizing 70% of your CPU, you're essentially wasting 30% of the value of it.  Set process priorities and let the OS figure it out.

Comment: Hi @Brad I updated my question to include the OS config. The question is how do I make sure the process does not take over the whole box? Because this is what's been happening so far...

Comment: What's the problem with it taking over the whole box?  Generally, that's desirable as long as there's a workload that actually needs to run.  Obviously, processes need to be prioritized in such a way that things remain fluid and aren't totally blocked.  What other processes are having trouble?

Comment: This may be helpful to you:  https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice

Comment: What about using a container with limited CPU usage? 

Comment: I thought the problem was that you're trying to limit CPU usage?  Is it CPU or memory?

Comment: Actually both! CPU and memory

Comment: You can limit the memory consumption, here is a link on how to do that: https://grizzlybit.info/blog/increase-nodejs-memory-limit

Answer (score 0):

Are you utilizing multiple cores to handle the loads? If you don't cluster then you are essentially running copies of the same process on all cores of your CPU. You might want to look into Node.js Cluster which might help with your performance issues:

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

[YouTube video on Clustering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xIbVPyh9wo)

Also, are you sure there are no memory leaks - these will gradually eat up your performance as well.

Comment: Thank, you, @Mike B. — No, I don't cluster, so I will look into it. Also, what would be the best way to check for memory leaks, in your opinion?

Comment: Sounds good! Graph the memory usage both client and server side for an extended period of time. If the usage keeps going up then you have a memory leak somewhere. For example, I created a memory leak recently in an alarm system application that I developed. My server connected to off site alarm panels and if the connection failed, my code was jumping straight to the .catch() block without closing the connection. This caused massive performance issues and my server kept crashing after a few days of operation.

Comment: This video might be useful to you for detecting and debugging memory leaks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hliOMEQRqf8